# Javascript function:return random picture

Tags: javascript

New to javascript. Im trying to code an external javascript function to randomly display a picture. There are 5 pictures are under a folder called "images/image1.jpg".

I have a couple alerts one called alert("test"); in the HTML and alert("me"); in the javascript external function these are not working as well. I don't know why this isn't working.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Winch-Lab8</title>
        <script src="scripts/random.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var randNumb;
        randNumb = randomInteger(5);
        alert("test");
        //This script calls the external function randomInteger() to display random pictures
        document.write("<img src="images/image" + randNumb + ".jpg" alt="Image" + randNumb");
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>

 //FUNCTION randomInteger()   
function randomInteger(n) {
    alert("me");
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * n);
}
```

Comment: What isn't working. Explain what you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this line is wrong:

```
document.write("<img src="images/image" + randNumb + ".jpg" alt="Image" + randNumb");
```

should be:

```
document.write("<img src='images/image" + randNumb + ".jpg' alt='Image" + randNumb + "'/>");
```

Comment: Considering that he doesn't get either of his alerts, I don't think it's even hitting that line of code.

Comment: The line could be causing an error, which would make the rest of the JS not run

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use google chrome console to see js errors:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Winch-Lab8</title>
        <script src="scripts/random.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var randNumb;
        randNumb = randomInteger(5);
        alert("test");
        //This script calls the external function randomInteger() to display random pictures
        document.write('<img src="images/image'+randNumb+'.jpg" alt="Image'+randNumb+'/>');
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>

 //FUNCTION randomInteger()   
function randomInteger(n) {
    alert("me");
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * n);
}
```

The error was the way you concat your vars in a string,
please see the diffrence on the code and understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've included a code snippet that does what you want, but I've removed the `document.write` code and replaced it with the more modern approach, which is to get a DOM reference to an image element and then just update the `src` attribute of that element.

Your big issue was the last line that concatenated the random number into the image element HTML. This is no longer needed if you use this more modern approach.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  
  var img = document.getElementById("pic");
  
  //FUNCTION randomInteger()   
  function randomInteger(n) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * n);
  }

  var randNumb = randomInteger(5);

  //This script calls the external function randomInteger() to display random pictures
  img.src = "image" + randomInteger(5) + ".jpg";
  
  alert(img.src);

});
```

```html
<img id="pic" src="">
```